# Trying to run a Gulp script that needs ruby on PHPStorm

Tags: ruby, shell, sass, gulp, phpstorm

I've edited a simple Gulp pipeline (that i've tested and works outside the IDE) and i'm now trying to include it into PHPStorm Project in order to achieve a better css workflow in a real project.

This is the script, (it's a simple css optimization pipeline):

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
     sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
     autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
     minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
     jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
     uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
     imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
     rename = require('gulp-rename'),
     concat = require('gulp-concat'),
     notify = require('gulp-notify'),
     cache = require('gulp-cache'),
     livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
     del = require('del');

// Styles
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return sass('../scss/base.scss', { style: 'expanded' })
    .pipe(autoprefixer('> 1%, last 2 versions, Firefox ESR, Opera 12.1'))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../css'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }));
});

// Clean
gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
    del(['css/base.css'], cb)
});

// Default task
gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function() {
    gulp.start('styles');
});
```

The annoying problem i cannot solve is related to the module sass that is the missing a proper ruby environment initialization, needed in order to run the command.

`sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass')` ->
'sass' not recognized as an internal or external command.

[image: Error Screen]

As i said before, I managed to run this gulp script using an external shell link from the ruby installer:

Start Command Prompt with Ruby

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /E:ON /K C:\Ruby21\bin\setrbvars.bat
```

Do you have any clue on how to run gulp scripts that needs ruby inside PhpStorm?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure that Ruby is in your system PATH - in Control Panel, go to System properties, Advanced, press `Environment variables`, in System variables section select PATH and append `C:\Ruby21\bin` to it. Make sure to restart PHPStorm after changing PATH

Comment: Seems your suggestion worked like a charm. Thank you very much!
I've also managed to repeat the success, reinstalling again Ruby with a clean environment, and installing sass gem within PHPStorm console.